# Does analytical solution for $a_i$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

For the system of $n$ equations ($i = 1, 2, ..., n)$ of the following kind:
$$P_i = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a_j + (7a_i+a_{i+1})/8$$
And assuming $a_1 = 0$ and $a_{n+1} = 0$, is there an analytical solution for $a_i$? If so, what is it?

Comment: An obvious simplification is to work out $P_{i+1} - P_i$ first, which I think gets the linear system of equations down to three non-zero diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

If the indices are right, then this is a lower triangular linear system on the unknowns $a_2, \dots, a_n$, whose diagonal entries are all equal to $1/8$. Therefore, it has a unique solution, which can be found by [forward substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution). It is easy to right a formula for the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved for a_2, and then used this to substitute a_2 when solving for a_3, however, it is still unclear to me how to get a generic solution for a_i. Would you please write out your solution?